# no page break between table and table caption

Tags: latex

I want to insert a non floating table with a caption above.
So I included the caption package and added my table:

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Kurvenparameter zur Parametrierung des Spulenstroms}
    \label{tab_kurvenparameter}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lllX}
        \toprule
        ... table content
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

The problem now: the table is to big for the rest of the page so it is placed on the next page. But the caption remains on the previuos page. So now my question is: How can I glue caption and table together?

Comment: Please don't post code fragments, always post compilable [mre]. It is very annoying having to add all the boring stuff like missing package before being able to test a possible solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can warp the whole thing in a minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Kurvenparameter zur Parametrierung des Spulenstroms}
    \label{tab_kurvenparameter}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lllX}
        \toprule
        ... table content\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```